# "Microsoft Visual C++ … is required" error when trying to install pyodbc on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, pyodbc

I am trying to install **pyodbc**, and I am getting the below error.

```
C:\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip3 install pyodbc
```

Output

```
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/71/cef225c4889620a1a00251d24c1746fe0cf4124290a75d1c2dc5c187b61f/pyodbc-4.0.23.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Alankar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7qf14pkz\\pyodbc\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Alankar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k11gmg0x\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

---

```
Command "c:\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Alankar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7qf14pkz\\pyodbc\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Alankar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k11gmg0x\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Alankar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7qf14pkz\pyodbc\
```

Comment: `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"` <-- Have you tried adressing this line?

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get the C++ build tools method to work, but I found this method to be very straightforward:

1. Download the relevant pyodbc wheel (pre-compiled binary) based on your computer's architecture and version of Python: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc
2. Run `pip install <wheel path>`.

For example:

```
pip install c:\users\bob\downloads\pyodbc-4.0.27-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for circumstances like the current situation with pyodbc 4.0.27 and Python 3.8. The next release of pyodbc will very likely include official wheels for Python 3.8 that will enable `pip install pyodbc`.

Comment: Great. It worked for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Some Libraries require C++ build tools to install. In your case, to solve this problem there are two methods which are:

**Update the pip's Setup tool:**

To fix your error update the setup tool by this command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

And the second method is to:

**Install the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools**

This can also be fixed by installing this little tool provided by Microsoft:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: I followed the second method and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft's build tools are not little; they require almost 3 GB to install.

Answer (score 2):

the install failed on my machine even after I installed Microsoft VC++ build tools, my solution for this is install an early version. the newer version assume you have VC++ and VS 2019 installed.

run this command

```
pip install -Iv pyodbc==4.0.27
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers work:
I was running the newest version of python and it was giving me this error.
As soon as I downgraded to 3.8.x it worked like a charm using pip install