# unable to install pyodbc using python 3.10 in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, django, odbc, pyodbc

I get this Error when I try to install Pyodbc , I have already install visual studio and I have Microsoft Visual C++ 12 , 15-19 in my machine but still its giving this error.

```
Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, asgiref, pyodbc, Django, Pillow, mssql-django, django-crispy-forms
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Athar\Desktop\New folder\Project\HeatlhCare\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Athar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w0wwm18g\\pyodbc_61963e883a8543fea24a63b1c522bbea\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Athar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w0wwm18g\\pyodbc_61963e883a8543fea24a63b1c522bbea\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Athar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t1td50y6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Athar\Desktop\New folder\Project\HeatlhCare\venv\include\site\python3.10\pyodbc'
         cwd: C:\Users\Athar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w0wwm18g\pyodbc_61963e883a8543fea24a63b1c522bbea\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running install
    C:\Users\Athar\Desktop\New folder\Project\HeatlhCare\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Athar\Desktop\New folder\Project\HeatlhCare\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Athar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w0wwm18g\\pyodbc_61963e883a8543fea24a63b1c522bbea\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Athar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w0wwm18g\\pyodbc_61963e883a8543fea24a63b1c522bbea\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Athar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t1td50y6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Athar\Desktop\New folder\Project\HeatlhCare\venv\include\site\python3.10\pyodbc' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632243/microsoft-visual-c-is-required-error-when-trying-to-install-pyodbc-on-wind

Comment: it didn't work I already tries every thing, @Limecat

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Updates - 2022-11-22:

1. pyodbc 4.0.34 started providing Windows wheel files for Python 3.10. pyodbc 4.0.35 started providing wheel files (including Windows) for Python 3.11. TL;DR - `pip install pyodbc` should "just work" on Windows for both 64-bit and 32-bit Python.
2. Christoph's wheel archive at [www.lfd.uci.edu](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc) is apparently no longer being updated.

---

*(original answer)*

The current release of pyodbc (4.0.32) does not have pre-built wheel files for Python 3.10. The easiest way to get it installed at the moment is to download the appropriate wheel from

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)

and then install it. For example, if you are running 64-bit Python then you would download the 64-bit wheel and use

```
pip install pyodbc‑4.0.32‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: what if install python 3.9 will it install pyodbc?

Comment: For 64-bit Python 3.9, yes. Unfortunately the [32-bit wheel for Python 3.9 is missing](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/960) too, so the workaround would be the same as above.

Comment: I must say the compile errors made no sense at all.  Thanks for this!

Comment: Despite having the correct wheel, this is throwing a 'not supported on this platform' error.

Comment: Good answer! Best solution for me was to avoid upgrading to Python 3.12 and just stay on 3.11 until pyodbc comes with a pre-built wheel that works with 3.12.

Answer (score 1):

After i downloaded the file, i used the command below to install:

```
python -m pip install <Path of downloaded file>.whl
```

Comment: That's the issue. There are no precompiled binaries (wheel files) for 3.10, at least not yet. So setup.py tries to build `pyodbc` from source.

Comment: PS D:\Py> python -m pip install .\pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win32.whl    
ERROR: pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Does not work for Python 3.11